# Linq, simple filter error...C#

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

Using linq and silverlight got this error....I am using POCO....DTO = POCO

```
public IEnumerable.....

var query = from d in Context.Documentos
            where d.CodigoEquipamento == documentoDTO.CodigoEquipamento &&
            d.Codigo == tipoEquipamentoDTO.Codigo 
            select new DocumentoDTO 
            {
                Codigo = d.Codigo, 
                CodigoEquipamento = d.CodigoEquipamento 
            }

 return query.AsEnumerable < DocumentoDTO>();
```

ERROR: The entity or complex type 'Model.DocumentoDTO' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.

```
 public class TipoEquipamentoDTO
{
    [Key]
    public virtual int Codigo { get; set; }
    public virtual string Tipo { get; set; }
    public virtual string UsuarioInclusao { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime DataHoraInclusao { get; set; }
    public virtual string UsuarioAlteracao { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime DataHoraAlteracao { get; set; }
    public ICollection<DocumentoDTO> DocumentoDTO { get; set; }
}

public class DocumentoDTO
{
    [Key]
    public virtual int Codigo { get; set; }
    public virtual int CodigoTipo { get; set; }
    public virtual int CodigoEquipamento { get; set; }
    public virtual byte[] Documento { get; set; }
    public virtual string Nome { get; set; }
    public virtual string UsuarioInclusao { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime DataHoraInclusao { get; set; }
    public virtual string UsuarioAlteracao { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime DataHoraAlteracao { get; set; }
    public TipoEquipamentoDTO TipoEquipamentoDTO { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Can you post the code of `Model.DocumentoDTO`?

Comment: You might need to add your objects to a collection of DocumentoDTO?

Comment: @brumScouse, I  guess not, thx for your attention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DocumentoDTO` is not an Entity Framework class, so you can't select to a type of `DocumentoDTO`. You'll have to execute the query first by calling `query.ToList()` only using Entity Framework classes. After that, you can select `DocumentoDTO`:

```
 public IEnumerable.....

var query = from d in Context.Documentos
            where d.CodigoEquipamento == documentoDTO.CodigoEquipamento &&
            d.Codigo == tipoEquipamentoDTO.Codigo 
            select new Documento { // Documento is in the context
               Codigo =d.Codigo, 
               CodigoEquipamento = d.CodigoEquipamento 
            });

 return query.ToList().Select(d => new DocumentoDTO 
                                       {
                                         Codigo = d.Codigo,
                                         CodigoEquipamento = d.CodigoEquipamento 
                                       });
```